# Java generics access error

Tags: java, generics

I could need some help with a problem I have with Java's generics.
I constructed a little example for to show what I mean.

`Handler`

```
package generalizingTest;

public class Handler<S extends Server<?>> {
    public S server;

    public Handler(S server) {
        this.server = server;
    }
}
```

`SubHandler`

```
package generalizingTest;

public class SubHandler<S extends Server<?>> extends Handler<S> {

    public SubHandler(S server) {
        super(server);
    }

    public void subHandlerMethod() {

    }

}
```

`Server`

```
package generalizingTest;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Server<H extends Handler<?>> {
    public ArrayList<H> handlers;

    public Server() {
        handlers = new ArrayList<H>();
    }

    public void addHandler(H c) {
        handlers.add(c);
    }
}
```

`SubServer`

```
package generalizingTest;

public class SubServer<H extends Handler<?>> extends Server<H> {
    public void subServerMethod() {

    }
}
```

[image: class diagram]

`Startup`

```
package generalizingTest;

public class Startup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server<Handler<?>> serverWHandler = new Server<Handler<?>>();
        Server<SubHandler<?>> serverWSubHandler = new Server<SubHandler<?>>();

        SubServer<Handler<?>> subServerWHandler = new SubServer<Handler<?>>();
        SubServer<SubHandler<?>> subServerWSubHandler = new SubServer<SubHandler<?>>();

        Handler<Server<?>> handlerWServer = new Handler<Server<?>>(serverWHandler);
        Handler<SubServer<?>> handlerWSubServer = new Handler<SubServer<?>>(subServerWHandler);

        SubHandler<Server<?>> subHandlerWServer = new SubHandler<Server<?>>(serverWSubHandler);
        SubHandler<SubServer<?>> subHandlerWSubServer = new SubHandler<SubServer<?>>(subServerWSubHandler);

        serverWHandler.addHandler(handlerWServer);
        subServerWHandler.addHandler(handlerWSubServer);

        serverWSubHandler.addHandler(subHandlerWServer);
        subServerWSubHandler.addHandler(subHandlerWSubServer);

        subServerWHandler.subServerMethod();
        subServerWSubHandler.subServerMethod();

        handlerWSubServer.server.subServerMethod();
        subHandlerWSubServer.server.subServerMethod();

        subHandlerWServer.subHandlerMethod();
        subHandlerWSubServer.subHandlerMethod();

        System.out.println(subHandlerWSubServer.server.handlers.get(0).getClass().getName()); // SubHandler

        //produces an error:
        /*
         * Unresolved compilation problem: 
         * The method subHandlerMethod() is undefined for the type Handler<capture#9-of ?>
         */
        //subHandlerWSubServer.server.handlers.get(0).subHandlerMethod();

    }
}
```

I just started learning about generics. They seem to be efficient but I am not sure if I solved the problem of the generics loop () correctly with the wildcard and why those errors occur.

I really hope someone can help me out.

EDIT:

So it seems like I did not highlighted the initial problem enough.
The following should be possible in any depth:

```
subHandlerWSubServer.server.handlers.get(0).server.handlers.get(0).server.handlers.get(0). ... .server.handlers.get(0).subHandlerMethod();
```

EDIT:

So this problem seems not to be solvable due to an endless loop of definition or the missing `self` value, see [Siguza’s anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41916217/3647724).
Here is the [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/134282) between [Siguza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2302862/siguza), [user889742](https://stackoverflow.com/users/889742/user889742) and [myself](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3647724/feirell) about this topic.

Comment: @MK. did you remove the comments down there ?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, but I don't think it makes sense.  Do you really need to have two classes specialized in terms of each other?  I can't imagine why you would ever need this.  It is not surprising that trying to express this unnatural incestious relationship is going to meet resistance from the language's type system.

Comment: @MK. the presented example needs this kind of relationship where both parties need to know all methods/member variables of the opposite which is achievable through generics

Comment: I don't understand what you are gaining by generics at all.  If the only difference between 2 instances of servers is which types of handlers they use, and the difference between handlers is which servers they go to, this collapses into a single server and a single handler classes w/o any loss of generality.  If the difference is that, say, some servers handle Integers and some Floats, then just generalize both Server and Handler in terms of <integer> vs <float>.

Comment: @MK. no it is about capability, any handler could be combinated with any server but both need to know the capabilities of each other so the access works correctly

Comment: That's what i'm saying -- if the only thing you are generecizing is that, you don't need generics at all.  What is the difference between two servers that you have?  You are saying: the only difference is which kinds of Handlers they take.  OK, what is the difference between two Handlers?  -- Which servers they go with.  This is a meaningless loop.

Comment: @MK. no it is not, bacause now the compiler knows what the type od the server / handler is, there could be any combination with a much higher amount of servers and handerls and code repetition is a not wanted

Comment: you are not answering my question. what is the  difference between different server classes?

Comment: @MK. They contain different capabilitys (methods and member variables)

Comment: well if interfaces are different, then you need to parallel hierarchies of Servers and Handlers.  Generics are not going to help you make different interfaces type safe.

Comment: In other words, what you are trying to conway should be captured by constructor/factory arguments I think.

Comment: @MK. That sounds like a good idea, I will trz this tomorrow (today)!

Comment: If you want to learn about java generics theres an excellent resource to be found here http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html especially the FAQ PDF http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.pdf

Comment: Hi, Feirell. Long time no chat... I now completely translated your code to my solution. ( All 4 Server-Handler cases ) . You can just copy the code in my answer and see that it works.

Comment: @user889742 I really appreciate your help I just commented your answer with a little problem I found

Comment: @MK. sorry but this idea did not solve the problem. I just updated the question with an addition question so my point gets clearer.

Comment: Sorry, but unless you make your question clear, i will not be able to help you.  You need to come up with an example of 2 servers and 2 handlers so that you and we can think through why there are different classes representing them.  Otherwise you are asking us to help you with your incorrect solution to an unspecified problem which is impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, if you have a `Handler<S>` you want all handlers on that server to be of type `Handler<S>`, right?
For that, `S.add()` would have to only accept objects of type `Handler<S>`. But in order to implement that in the base class `Server`, you would need `S`, so that:

```
public class Server<H>
{
    public ArrayList<H<S>> handlers;

    public Server()
    {
        handlers = new ArrayList<H<S>>();
    }

    public void addHandler(H<S> c)
    {
        handlers.add(c);
    }
}
```

The only problem with this is that `S` is not defined, and you cannot easily define it. What you would need is something that, in the context of `Server`, means `Server`, and in the context of `SubServer`, means `SubServer`. Basically `this.getClass()`, but as a compile-time type expression. If Java had a keyword for that, say `self`, you could use it like this:

```
public class Server<H>
{
    public ArrayList<H<self>> handlers;

    public Server()
    {
        handlers = new ArrayList<H<self>>();
    }

    public void addHandler(H<self> c)
    {
        handlers.add(c);
    }
}
```

Then `Server.add()` would take `Handler<Server>`, and `SubServer.add()` would take `Handler<SubServer>`.

Sadly, [Java has no such thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18443418), therefore what you're trying to do is not possible this way.

Java does many things well.
Generics aren't one of them.

Comment: But how could I solve this? Any attempt I could imagine would result into a endless recursion at the generics definition. The `instance of` solution seems to be not like it was intended to be the default approach.

Comment: `SubHandler<SubServer<?>> subHandlerWSubServer = new SubHandler<SubServer<?>>(subServerWSubHandler);` shouldn't that prevent exactly that case so there can't be any super class of SubHandler?

Answer (score 1):

It could work with a redesign like this. You would not be able to use Server as your starting point, since it would require generic arguments leading to a recursive definition again. Instead, start with ServerInfo. As you can check it works, but I think it might be a bit cumbersome and not intuitive.

```
class Server
{

}
class Handler
{

}
class SubServer extends Server
{

}
class SubHandler extends Handler
{
    public void subHandlerMethod(){}
}

class HandlerInfo<S extends Server, H extends Handler>
{
    ServerInfo<S,H> serverInfo;
    H handler;
}
class ServerInfo<S extends Server, H extends Handler>
{
    S server;
    ArrayList<HandlerInfo<S,H>> handlerInfo = new ArrayList<>();
}




public class Example {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server s = new Server();
        SubHandler h = new SubHandler();
        ServerInfo<Server,SubHandler> serverInfo = new ServerInfo<>();
        HandlerInfo<Server,SubHandler> handlerInfo = new HandlerInfo<>();
        handlerInfo.serverInfo = serverInfo;
        handlerInfo.handler = h;
        serverInfo.server = s;
        serverInfo.handlerInfo.add(handlerInfo);
        serverInfo.handlerInfo.get(0).serverInfo.handlerInfo.get(0).handler.subHandlerMethod();

     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! That approach seems to work which is fantastic. I will spare to mark it as the correct solition just to see if ther a pure generics answer. Never less thank you for your idea.

Comment: again -- you keep insisting on a generics-based answer to a question you haven't asked

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

You could simply restrict SubServers to only accept SubHandlers

```
Subserver<H extends SubHandler> extends Server<H>
```

When you do that you will see that the compilation error goes away.
But I understand you want to define some Servers that allow only subHandlers, and some subHandlers that allow only Servers. ( Seems strange to me ), and then reflexive relationship H<->S gives you trouble, leading to generic type recursion.
While I think it's strange to mix Server->Subhandler and Handler->SubServer , you could accomplish an unrestricted 2 way relationship as you want by extracting interfaces like this: ( try it, it works )

```
interface IHandler
{

}
interface IServer
{

}
interface ISubServer extends IServer
{
     public void subServerMethod();
}
interface ISubHandler extends IHandler
{
    public void subHandlerMethod();
}

class Handler<S extends IServer> implements IHandler {
    public S server;

    public Handler(S server) {
        this.server = server;
    }
}

class SubHandler<S extends IServer> extends Handler<S> implements ISubHandler {

    public SubHandler(S server) {
        super(server);
    }

    public void subHandlerMethod() {

    }

}

class Server<H extends IHandler> implements IServer{
    public ArrayList<H> handlers;

    public Server() {
        handlers = new ArrayList<H>();
    }

    public void addHandler(H c) {
        handlers.add(c);
    }
}

class SubServer<H extends IHandler> extends Server<H> implements ISubServer {
    public void subServerMethod() {

    }
}



public class Example {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            Server<IHandler> serverWHandler = new Server<IHandler>();
            Server<ISubHandler> serverWSubHandler = new Server<ISubHandler>();

            SubServer<IHandler> subServerWHandler = new SubServer<IHandler>();
            SubServer<ISubHandler> subServerWSubHandler = new SubServer<ISubHandler>();

            Handler<IServer> handlerWServer = new Handler<IServer>(serverWHandler);
            Handler<ISubServer> handlerWSubServer = new Handler<ISubServer>(subServerWHandler);

            SubHandler<Server<ISubHandler>> subHandlerWServer = new SubHandler<Server<ISubHandler>>(serverWSubHandler);
            SubHandler<SubServer<ISubHandler>> subHandlerWSubServer = new SubHandler<SubServer<ISubHandler>>(subServerWSubHandler);

            serverWHandler.addHandler(handlerWServer);
            subServerWHandler.addHandler(handlerWSubServer);

            serverWSubHandler.addHandler(subHandlerWServer);
            subServerWSubHandler.addHandler(subHandlerWSubServer);

            subServerWHandler.subServerMethod();
            subServerWSubHandler.subServerMethod();

            handlerWSubServer.server.subServerMethod();
            subHandlerWSubServer.server.subServerMethod();

            subHandlerWServer.subHandlerMethod();
            subHandlerWSubServer.subHandlerMethod();

            System.out.println(subHandlerWSubServer.server.handlers.get(0).getClass().getName()); // SubHandler

            //no longer produces an error:
            subHandlerWSubServer.server.handlers.get(0).subHandlerMethod();

        }

}
```

and remember, anytime your problem is a reflexive relationship A<->B , not just with generics, you can extract IA and IB so that A->IB and B-> IA

Comment: Thank you! But how might I fix this ?

Comment: If you are sure that the list will only contain SubHandlers, declare it as a list of subHandlers.

Comment: I just edited the question the first error is gone (made `ArrayList<Handler<?>>` to `ArrayList<H>`) but the second is still there

Comment: Well, you are still only convincing the compiler that it is a list of Handler, not SubHandler, so he is not going to let you call a method found only in SubHandler.

Comment: Can't I keep it generic?

Comment: If you want to keep the list in the base class, the only thing I can think of is creating a get method in the derived ( subserver ) class that hard casts handler to subhandler for the client

Comment: Mhh ok that might work. But I really hoped I would get rid of casting with generics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134282/discussion-between-user889742-and-feirell).

Comment: I just tried to apply your idea but it results in the same problem. In the third level e.g.: `System.out.println(version2.handlers.get(0).server.handlers);` the compiler matches against the interface and not the class anymore therefore it will not work for any more depths.

Comment: Thanks for you help, but your solution just shifted the problem one level.
For example you could not do something like `subHandlerWSubServer.server.handlers.get(0).server;` because he uses the interface and not the class anymore. The next level isn't even declared. The same solution is archivable if you replace `SubHandler<SubServer<SubHandler<?>>>` with `SubHandler<SubServer<SubHandler<SubServer<?>>>>`